# Where are the logs of the gnome vino-server?

Tags: gnome, logging

I've a machine with gnome & ubuntu maverick. Desktop sharing enabled. I want to know who as connected (the sharing is password protected)

Where are stored the logs of vino server, if they are any?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dpkg -L vino` doesn't show anything created in /var/log so i guess there are no logs.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, you can get logs with vino.

Write a shell script for execute vino-server, redirecting it's output to a file. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server --sm-disable 2>&1 | tee -a ~/.local/share/vino/log
```

Now, go to gnome menu bar "System -> Preferences -> Startup applications", uncheck "Remote Desktop" and add a new one. Give it a name, like "Remote Desktop w/Log" and select the shell script with the "Browse" button. Save it and log out.
The next time you log in you should have something in ~/.local/share/vino/log

I used this in Debian 6.0 Squeeze with GNOME 2.30

Comment: Thank you for this. I can't believe something like this isn't the default! Quick note for linux mint users, there's no "startup applications" entry for vino, but there's a `/etc/xdg/autostart/vino-server.desktop` file that seems to be autostarted at login, and this can be edited to point to the modified script (NOTE: putting the command in directly doesn't work because of spaces etc. create a script as above). Also, make sure to create the `.local/share/vino` directory *first* for this to work (I'm embarrassed to admit it took me a while to figure out that was the reason this wasn't working! )